# Regular graph with two eigenvalues is complete

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Problem**

Let $\Gamma$ be a $k$-regular graph with $n$ vertices and suppose it has only two eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}$. Show that $\Gamma$ is $n$-complete.

**Attempt**

Since it is $k$-regular it must have eigenvalue $\lambda_1=k$ with eigenvector $j$ (all ones) and multiplicity 1. The eigenvalues must sum to 0 so the second eigenvalue must be $\lambda_2=-\frac{k}{n-1}$ (since it has multiplicity $n-1$). I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I think it is sufficient to show that $k=n-1$ or equivalently that $A=J-I$ where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $\Gamma$ and $J$ is the $n\times n$ all ones matrix, but i'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to finish off the problem is linear algebra: if $\lambda_2 = -\frac{k}{n-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $n-1$, then $A - \lambda_2 I$ is a rank $1$ matrix: all its rows are multiples of each other.

Playing around a bit with the entries of $A - \lambda_2 I$ (which has $-\lambda_2$ on the diagonal and $0$'s and $1$'s off the diagonal) should convince you that this is only possible when $\lambda_2 = -1$ and $A-\lambda_2 I = J$, which tells you what the graph is.

(Note that technically there is a somewhat more general class of graphs possible here: the disjoint union of a bunch of complete graphs of the same size also has only two eigenvalues. Your solution works if we assume $\Gamma$ is connected: you use that when you say that $\lambda_1 = k$ has multiplicity $1$. If $\Gamma$ is not connected, we can just apply the argument to each connected component.)